# Not able to select multiple columns while creating a dataframe from another panda dataframe and applying Groupby on the same

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda dataframe 'pf2'. 
I have a code where i execute the following statement :

```
agg_geo = pf2.groupby('A')['B', 'C', 'D', 'F']
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Im getting following error :

KeyError: "('B', 'C', 'D', 'F')"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a list to select columns. Try this:

```
agg_geo = pf2.groupby('A')[['B', 'C', 'D', 'F']]
```

**EDIT:**
You also need to do some kind of operation, like a **count** for example. The groupby alone doesn't do anything.

```
agg_geo = pf2.groupby('A').count()[['B', 'C', 'D', 'F']]
```

Comment: Then Im getting following error : TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Yes, i assume you need to perform an operation, beacuse the "groupBy" alone doesn't do anything. I will edit my answer to show you.